# Line wrap in div breaks format in Safari only

Tags: css, safari

I have a strange css problem that appears to exist only in Safari.

I have rows of 5 boxes.  There is no attempt to make this responsive, each box is 160px wide and they fit within a set width container of 900px.

See here: http://bit.ly/1rs97IB

In Safari only, when a box title wraps onto two lines, the whole box is pushed upwards outside of the row.  This does not happen within IE, Opera, Firefox or Chrome.  Can anyone work out what might be causing this and suggest an approach to fixing it?  It's driving me a bit nuts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting I came up with this: Change the display to flex for two of the containers.

```
.post_gallery_row {
    margin-bottom: 21px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.post_gallery_item {
    width: 160px;
    margin-right: 21px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
```

I have no idea what specifically caused the error, but this is something atleast and I hope it helps.

Comment: On a side note: I think it'd be better if you removed the row class and then put all items in one container, that way it's possible to make the items automatically line break if the window becomes narrow.

Comment: Oh I noticed that in chrome the row shrinks when the window does, but it doesn't in safari :(

Comment: Yes, I think that's due to the display being set to flex, as before it  wrapped (which was a bit rubbish anyway).  The next thing for me to work on I think!